# PHP - Ajax call won't run API without wait / print_r

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api

I have a script that runs with jQuery via onClick event, I pass some information through that function. Here is my Event script.

```
$.post("page.php", { ... }, function(ret){ alert(ret); });
```

In **page.php**, I call an API for sending message, the page is completely PHP, no HTML is there. Everything works fine but message not send. But if i run the same page directly from web (without ajax call) run and send message.

**page.php**

```
$params = array(
    'str'  => $sms_content, // sms content
    'num'   => $cell_no,    // mobile number
);

$url = '.....api.php?'. http_build_query($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $result = curl_error($ch);
    $str = 'send message fail';
} else{
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $str = 'send message success';
}
echo $str;
```

> **Note:** If i add an `print_r()` in the **page.php** page then the API send messages.

What is the problem, what can i do??

Comment: Please insert complete code here.

Comment: some API issue; **Note:** If i run `page.php` directly (without ajax) its fine. But the problem is with ajax.

Comment: Can you post the code in **page.php**?

Comment: `page.php` code added

Comment: What is the value of `$cell_no`? I mean where do you get it? from `$_GET`. Or if your calling this php script from jQuery do you pass the cell number?

Comment: yes i pass this as parameter from `$.post(....)` here.

Comment: One more thing, always i get a return value `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax directly to the api

```
    $params = {
        str:sms_content, // sms content
        num:cell_no    // mobile number
    };

  $.get("...api.php", { ... }, function(ret){ alert(ret); });
```

Comment: Yes i did this. That is not the problem.

Comment: I don't need actually get the return message from that page, I need only the API working.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: why aren't you ajaxing to the api directly??

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: use the url of the api in your ajax not the local php page

Comment: what errors do you have in the console,this is a valid way,its secure when you use ssl