# Ajax call response correctly but won't run cURL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I have a script that runs with `jQuery` via `onClick` event, I pass some information through that function. Here is my Event script.

```
$.post("page.php", { id : some_id }, function(ret){ alert(ret); });
```

In `page.php`, i have a database connection, from the jquery i pass an **id** query it in **page.php** and run some cURL inside loop.

**page.php**

```
include_once "../inc/db_con.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT `mobile` FROM `table` WHERE `id`= '".$id."'";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_object($qry);

$message = 'Hello! from the website.';

$mobile = explode("###", trim($data->mobile));

foreach ($mobile as $key => $value) {
  $params = array(
      'message'  => $message,
      'number'   => $value,
      'sender'   => "mobile_number",
      'username' => "username",
      'password' => "password",
      'type'     => 0
  );

  $url = 'http://_valid_ip_/api.php?'.http_build_query($params);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
if($qry)
    echo "State Changed.";
else
    echo "State Not Changed.";
```

In this case this page just response **State Changed.** and message not send to mobile.

> *But if i manually run the **page.php** with setting the id = 2, it runs fine and message send to mobile.*

What should i do to make my page run the API correctly and send messages. I make [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565005/php-ajax-call-wont-run-api-without-wait-print-r) but not get any benefited answer.

Comment: 1) Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection 2) Did you try putting some debug output into your loop?

Comment: like? how can i add this?

Comment: Umm.... `echo $url;` for example? `echo $output;` ? All of that will be visible in the JS alert box since you just alert what's returned by the request.

Comment: As i said "But if i manually run the page.php with setting the id = 2, it runs fine and message send to mobile."

Comment: also if i add some `print_r` to the `$output` or `$params` than the API works perfectly and send messages, But i can't do it like that.

Comment: Where is `$qryUpdate` that you use in `if()` even defined? And what are you doing with cUrl repsonse? And how are you checking  error handling of the ajax? Lots of unknowns here

Comment: Print out the URLs to be sure they're correct... you're not showing where `some_id` in your JS comes from... it could be `NaN` or `undefined` for all we know... which would result in 0 results for your query.

Comment: You have to check if the `id` passed is empty before sending. You can `console.log(id);` or `alert(id)` and see if the `id` is an empty string

Comment: The `id` and `url` both is fine..., Is there any problem with HTML Tags??? I mean is it necessary to add some html container for a PHP page that is called by ajax??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ajax call here. Can you hit the api url directly, i.e; 'http://_valid_ip_/api.php?'.http_build_query($params) to check what are you getting in result? Comment these codes out "if($qry)
    echo "State Changed.";
else
    echo "State Not Changed.";
"  and add echo $url; to get the exact url and make a direct hit on the $url.

Comment: Second thing is you are echoing if($qry)
    echo "State Changed.";
else
    echo "State Not Changed.";
 which has nothing to do with your curl request. I don't understand what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your prev question does makes some sense though